# Wordpress: Custom Search

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make custom search

This is the output url from the form `http://alessandro.host/?country=Italy&area=Milan&type=luxury-hotels`

and this is the explanation:

- $_GET['country'] => this is value from `post_meta`
- $_GET['area'] => this is value from `post_meta`
- $_GET['type'] => this is the post category

how i can make this custom search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd check out scribu's explanation of advanced metadata queries in WordPress 3.1 to help you:
http://scribu.net/wordpress/advanced-metadata-queries.html

Also, take a look at WordPress's documentation on WP_Query:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query

In your case, it sounds like all you'd need is something like this:

```
<?php

$country = $_GET['country'];
$area = $_GET['area'];
$type = $_GET['type'];

query_posts( array(
    'category_name' => $type,        
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'country',
            'value' => $country,
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'area',
            'value' => $area,
        )
    )
) );

// now do the loop as normal

?>
```